# pygame.Surface' object is not callable

Tags: python

I already search trough some questions but it didn't really answer my question.

I'm new to Python & Pygame, it's a few weeks now :), doing a tutorial about game development.
I have a code here & it should show my bug image on the screen but it doesn't, instead I get a black window...
Where did I go wrong??

```
import pygame, sys


pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = (800, 600)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT),0, 32)
img_bug = pygame.image.load("bug.png").convert_alpha()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()    
FPS = 24
fivesecondinterval = FPS * 5
totalframes = 0

while True: #Never ending loop
for event in pygame.event.get():   
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:           
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

totalframes += 1

if totalframes % fivesecondinterval ==0 :

screen.blit(img_bug, (200, 200))
pygame.display.flip()   
clock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to correctly indent your code. This should work:

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = (800, 600)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT),0, 32)
img_bug = pygame.image.load("bug.png").convert_alpha()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()    
FPS = 24
fivesecondinterval = FPS * 5
totalframes = 0

while True: #Never ending loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():   
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:           
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    totalframes += 1

    if totalframes % fivesecondinterval ==0 :
        screen.blit(img_bug, (200, 200))
        pygame.display.flip()   
            clock.tick(FPS)
```

The importand part is that (after fixing every indentation error which caused an exception) this:

```
if totalframes % fivesecondinterval==0:
    screen.blit(img_bug, (200, 200))
    pygame.display.flip()   
        clock.tick(FPS)
```

part of the code is inside the loop.